# Can you link multiple product keys to a single Microsoft account?

Tags: windows, microsoft-account

In Windows you can *link* your *Product key* to a *Microsoft account*. Is there a limit for how many product keys you can have?

Answer (score 1):

You can have at least ten but I've seen suggestions that you can have up to 30.